# mvn exec:java doesn't set classpath properly

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to run a Java program with Maven on the commandline, but it is not putting the correct entries on the classpath. If I run the program in IntelliJ (which has Maven support), the classpath has 80 or so entries including my project's jar dependencies, the compile program classes, and the resources from src/main/resources. If I run the program with `mvn exec:java`, I only get one entry for `apache-maven-3.0.4/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar`. There are no references to `plexus` in my entire project tree. Where is this entry coming from and why are the other expected classpath entries not there?

Maven version: `Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 00:44:56-0800)`

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
<version>SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- lots of dependencies -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.MyApp</mainClass>
                <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/java</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please show your full pom otherwise it's impossible to help in any way. Furthermore it would be helpful which maven version do you use? Which version of exec-maven-plugin ? etc.

Comment: I've updated my question with the pom and Maven version, thank you.

Comment: First try to update [exec-maven-plugin to newest version which is 1.3.2](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

Answer (score 3):

By default, the exec:java uses the 'runtime' scope, which will not bring your dependencies set with the 'compile' scope.

You can use:

```
exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope="compile"
```

To include the compile dependencies (not 100% sure about the -D syntax, but the variable is exec.classpathScope for sure).

This should do the trick.
If you need more info/options, the plugin page has some options listed: http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html

Comment: I tried running with `mvn exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope="compile"`, but am still having the same problem. I also tried `-Dexec.includeProjectDependencies=true` and `-Dexec.includePluginsDependencies=true` but neither had any effect.

Comment: includeProjectDependencies and includePluginsDependencies are not necessary. However classpathScope is, you must have (at least) one other problem. Have you tried 'mvn dependency:tree' to understand where the plexus dependency comes from ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Plexus (I would guess it is a dependency of the Exec Maven Plugin?) , but try running with debugging turned on: `mvn exec:java -X` and it should be more clear that your dependencies are being added to the classpath:

```
....
[DEBUG] Invoking : com.example.MyApp.main()
[DEBUG] Plugin Dependencies will be excluded.
[DEBUG] Project Dependencies will be included.
[DEBUG] Collected project artifacts [log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile]
[DEBUG] Collected project classpath [C:\MyProject\target\classes]
[DEBUG] Adding to classpath : file:/C:/MyProject/target/classes/
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: log4j to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: commons-lang to classpath
....
```

You should see lots of the "Adding project dependency artifact" messages.

Answer (score 0):

configure the classpath in the pom:

`<argument>-classpath</argument>`

https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html